# Need help in solving an equation involving volume, single and double layer potentials

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, gaussian-integral, potential-theory

Let be $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n $, $ 3\leq n$ an open set, where you can apply Gauß's Theorem.

To show is, that for all $ U \in C^{(1)} ( \bar{V} ) \cap C^{(2)} (V) $ with  bounded 2nd derivatives the following equation for $y \in V $:

$$ (n-2) \omega_{n-1} U(y) = \int_{ \partial V} \left[\frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}} \frac{ \partial U}{ \partial \nu} (x)-U(x) \frac{ \partial }{\partial \nu_x} \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\right] d\sigma(x)- \int_V \frac{ \Delta U(x)}{ |x-y|^{n-2}} dx $$

where

- $ \nu_x $ is the outer normal unit vector on $x\in \partial V$ and
- $w_{n-1} := \frac{n \pi^{n/2}}{ \Gamma( \frac{n}{2} +1) }$

Well, I know that $W(x):= |x-y|^{-(n-2)} $ is not defined in $x=y$.
Therefore, instead of integrating over $V$ , first integrate over $V_{\epsilon}:= V$ \ $ K_{\epsilon}(y) $ and use the limes $\epsilon \rightarrow 0+ $

Thats pretty much it. Do you guys maybe know what that is for an Equation? I didn't know a proper title for the question, sorry about that. I find it quite hard to solve.

Any help is therefore very appreciated !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a bit the notation from the original post, and added sections in order to give a better answer.
 Let's start by recalling, as supinf does in his answer, that the above formula is a consequence of [Green's second identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities#Green's_second_identity) 
$$
\int\limits_V \big[U(x)\Delta W(x) - W(x)\Delta U(x)\big]\mathrm{d}x = \int\limits_{\partial V}\bigg[U(x)\frac{ \partial W(x)}{ \partial \nu_x}-W(x)\frac{ \partial U(x)}{ \partial \nu_x}\bigg] \mathrm{d}\sigma_x\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
However, it is not needed to consider a deleted neighborhood of $y$, i.e. $V(y,\epsilon)\triangleq V\setminus B(y,\epsilon)$, where $B(y,\epsilon)$ is the $n$-dimensional ball of radius $\epsilon>0$ centered at $y\in\Bbb R^n$. It is sufficient to recall that, for $n\geq 3$,
$$
\Delta \frac{1}{|y-x|^{n-2}}=-(n-2)\omega_{n-1} \delta(x-y)=-(n-2)\omega_{n-1} \delta(y-x)\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
where $\delta$ is the usual *Dirac distribution* supported at $y\in\Bbb R^n$, and the laplacian is calculated respect to the $x$ variable. Then, putting
$$
W(x)=\frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\quad\text{for an arbitrary }y\in\Bbb R^n
$$
in formula \eqref{1}, at the left side we get
$$
\begin{split}
\int\limits_V \big[U(x)\Delta W(x) - W(x)\Delta U(x)\big]\mathrm{d}x &= \int\limits_V \bigg[U(x)\Delta \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}} - \frac{\Delta U(x)}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\bigg]\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int\limits_V \bigg[U(x)\Delta \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}} - \frac{\Delta U(x)}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\bigg]\mathrm{d}x\\
&= -(n-2)\omega_{n-1}\int\limits_V U(x)\delta(y-x)\mathrm{d}x - \int\limits_V\frac{\Delta U(x)}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\mathrm{d}x\\
&= -(n-2)\omega_{n-1}U(y)- \int\limits_V\frac{\Delta U(x)}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\mathrm{d}x
\end{split}
$$
while at the second side we simply have
$$
\int\limits_{\partial V}\bigg[U(x)\frac{ \partial W(x)}{ \partial \nu_x}-W(x)\frac{ \partial U(x)}{ \partial \nu_x}\bigg] \mathrm{d}\sigma_x =\int\limits_{ \partial V} \left[U(x) \frac{ \partial }{\partial \nu_x} \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}} - \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}} \frac{ \partial U(x)}{ \partial \nu_x}\right] \mathrm{d}\sigma(x)
$$
From these two relations, you immediately get the sought for formula.

**How to prove directly, without using distribution theory, the following equality, key relation of the whole proof?**
$$
\int\limits_V U(x)\Delta \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\mathrm{d}x=-(n-2)\omega_{n-1}U(y)\quad\forall y\in V\label{3}\tag{3}
$$
I added this section since it seems that the main problem posed the OP is how to prove this fact (and thus the above statement) by using a classical "hard analysis" argument.
 The first thing to note is that the integral at the left side of \eqref{3} should be intended in a generalized sense: *it cannot be evaluated by using the limit expression* 
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int\limits_{V_\epsilon} U(x)\Delta \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\mathrm{d}x,
$$
since $|x-y|^{2-n}$ is *harmonic* on every deleted neighborhood of $y$, i.e.
$$
\Delta \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}}=0\text{ on }V(y,\epsilon)\implies \int\limits_{V_\epsilon} U(x)\Delta \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\mathrm{d}x=0\quad\forall\epsilon>0.\label{a}\tag{*}
$$ 
However we can use \eqref{a} and \eqref{1} by defining, for each $B(y,\epsilon)\Subset V$,
$$
\begin{split}
\int\limits_{V} U(x)\Delta \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\mathrm{d}x & \triangleq \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int\limits_{B(y,\epsilon)} U(x)\Delta \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\mathrm{d}x \\
 \triangleq \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\,&
 \left[ \,\int\limits_{B(y,\epsilon)}\frac{\Delta U(x)}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\mathrm{d}x + \int\limits_{ \partial B(y,\epsilon)} \left[U(x) \frac{ \partial }{\partial \nu_x} \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}} - \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}} \frac{ \partial U(x)}{ \partial \nu_x}\right] \mathrm{d}\sigma(x)\right]
\end{split}
$$ 
and, since 
$$
\int\limits_{B(y,\epsilon)}\frac{\Delta U(x)}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\mathrm{d}x\underset{\epsilon \to 0}{\longrightarrow} 0
$$
because $U\in C^2(V)\iff \Delta U\in  C^0(V)$ and $|x-y|^{2-n} \in L^1_\mathrm{loc}(\Bbb R^n)$ for $n \ge 2$, we finally get
$$
\int\limits_{V} U(x)\Delta \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\mathrm{d}x \triangleq \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int\limits_{ \partial B(y,\epsilon)} \left[U(x) \frac{ \partial }{\partial \nu_x} \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}} - \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}} \frac{ \partial U(x)}{ \partial \nu_x}\right] \mathrm{d}\sigma(x)
$$
Now let's evaluate each term of the right member of this "definition", by passing to hyperspherical coordinates $x\mapsto (r,\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_{n-1})$: for the first one we have
$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int\limits_{ \partial B(y,\epsilon)} U(x) \frac{ \partial }{\partial \nu_x} \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}}  \mathrm{d}\sigma(x)&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int\limits_{ \partial B(y,\epsilon)} U \frac{ \partial }{\partial r} \frac{1}{r^{n-2}}\mathrm{d}\sigma\\
&=-\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{n-2}{\epsilon^{n-1}} \int\limits_{ \partial B(y,\epsilon)} U \mathrm{d}\sigma\\
&=-(n-2) \omega_{n-1} \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left[\frac{1}{\omega_{n-1}\epsilon^{n-1}}\int\limits_{ \partial B(y,\epsilon)} U \mathrm{d}\sigma \right]\\ 
&= -(n-2) \omega_{n-1} U(y)
\end{split}
$$
since the integral within square brackets is nothing less than the *spherical mean* of the $C^2$ function $U(x)$ over the sphere $\partial B(y,\epsilon)$. For the second one we have
$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int\limits_{ \partial B(y,\epsilon)}  \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}} \frac{ \partial U(x)}{ \partial \nu_x}\mathrm{d}\sigma(x) &= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int\limits_{ \partial B(y,\epsilon)} \frac{1}{r^{n-2}} \frac{ \partial U }{\partial r} \mathrm{d}\sigma \\
 &= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}  \frac{1}{\epsilon^{n-2}}\int\limits_{ \partial B(y,\epsilon)} \frac{ \partial U}{\partial r} \mathrm{d}\sigma \\
&= \omega_{n-1} \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}  \epsilon \cdot \left[\frac{1}{\omega_{n-1} \epsilon^{n-1}}\int\limits_{ \partial B(y,\epsilon)} \frac{ \partial U}{\partial r} \mathrm{d}\sigma\right] \\
&=0
\end{split}
$$
since the integral within the square brackets is the spherical mean of the $C^1$ function $\nabla U(x)$ over the sphere $\partial B(y,\epsilon)$. This last step proves equation \eqref{3} and thus the formula in the OP question.

**Notes**

- In many mathematical physics texts, the OP's formula is called Green's formula (see for example [1], chapter IV, §2.1, p. 318 and [2], §4.9.2, pp. 69).
- The "soft analysis" (distribution theory) approach described in the first part of the answer is similar to the one proposed by Vladimirov ([2], §4.9.2, pp. 69-70), though adapted to the question notation, while the "hard analysis" proof of \eqref{3} is inspired to the one given by Tikhonov and Samarskii [1], chapter IV, §2.1, pp. 316-318) who, however, deal only with the case $n=3$ and work on the whole formula \eqref{1} in order to avoid the difficulties intrinsically inherent to the definition of the first member of \eqref{3}. Each of these approaches has its own merits, the firs one being conceptually simpler but requiring considerable more background, while the second one requiring some more analytical machinery, however interesting *per se*.

[1] A. N. Tikhonov and A. A. Samarskii (1990) [1963], "*[Equations of mathematical physics](https://books.google.it/books?id=PTmoAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=it#v=onepage&q&f=false)*", New York: Dover Publications, pp. XVI+765 ISBN 0-486-66422-8, [MR0165209](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0165209), [Zbl 0111.29008](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0111.29008).

[2] V. S. Vladimirov (2002), *[Methods of the theory of generalized functions](https://books.google.it/books?id=6UpZDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=it#v=onepage&q&f=false)*, Analytical Methods and Special Functions, 6, London–New York: Taylor & Francis, pp. XII+353, ISBN 0-415-27356-0, [MR2012831](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR2012831), [Zbl 1078.46029](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1078.46029).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough sketch on how I think this equation can be shown.

As you stated, we should work on the domain $V_\epsilon$ instead of $V$ first.
The other important idea is to use [Green's seocond identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities#Green's_second_identity).

So we apply Green's second identity to the domain $V_\epsilon$.
If we also use that $\Delta W(x)=0$ for $x\neq y$ then the equation becomes
$$
(n-2) \omega_{n-1} U(y) = \int_{ \partial K_\epsilon} \left[\frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}} \frac{ \partial U}{ \partial \nu} (x)-U(x) \frac{ \partial }{\partial \nu_x} \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}}\right] d\sigma(x).
$$
Note that the terms involving integrals over $V$ or $\partial V$ disappeared.

Now we will work with the right-hand side and consider the convergence $\epsilon\to0$.
First we consider the first term of the integral.
Because the second derivatives of $U$ are bounded it means that the first derivatives of $U(x)$
are bounded by a constant $C$ if $x$ is close to $y$.
We have
$$
\left|\int_{ \partial K_\epsilon} frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}} \frac{ \partial U}{ \partial \nu} (x) d\sigma(x)\right|
\leq
C \int_{ \partial K_\epsilon} \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}} d\sigma(x)
= C \epsilon^{2-n} \omega_{n-1} \epsilon^{n-1}\to 0,
$$
where we used that the surface area of a ball with radius $\epsilon>0$ is given by $\omega_{n-1}\epsilon^{n-1}$.

So it remains to consider the other term.
First, we can calculate that
$$
\frac{ \partial }{\partial \nu_x} \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}}
=  -(n-2) \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-1}}.
$$
Then we have
$$
\int_{ \partial K_\epsilon} U(x) \frac{ \partial }{\partial \nu_x} \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-2}} d\sigma(x)
= 
-(n-2) \epsilon^{-(n-1)} \int_{ \partial K_\epsilon} U(x) d\sigma(x).
$$
It remains to consider the difference to the left-hand side of the original equation.
$$
\left|
(n-2)\omega_{n-1} U(y)
-(n-2) \epsilon^{-(n-1)} \int_{ \partial K_\epsilon} U(x) d\sigma(x)
\right|
=\left|
(n-2) \epsilon^{-(n-1)} \int_{ \partial K_\epsilon} U(y)-U(x) d\sigma(x)
\right|
\leq \sup_{x\in \partial K_\epsilon} |U(y)-U(x)| (n-2)\epsilon^{-(n-1)}\omega_{n-1} \epsilon^{n-1}
\to0
$$
where the $\sup$-term converges to $0$ because $U$ is continuous.

Comment: firstly; thank you so much !. I got it till the part where to show that one of the two right-hand side terms are left. I don't know how to proceed showing that one Term is converging to 0 and for the other part as well..It would be awesome if you could show me some details ! :)

Comment: @constant94 i added some more details.